# if command in find -exec

Tags: bash, shell, find, command-substitution

I was just trying to list all directories and files under current directory and also write if they are file or directory with the following command:

```
find -exec echo `echo {} : ;if [ -f {} ]; then echo file; else echo directory;fi` \;
```

I know it is a silly command, I can use other things like `-type f` or `-type d`, but I want to learn why that piece of code did not work as I expected. It just prints directory to all of them. For example while output of `find` is:

```
.
./dir
./dir/file
```

output of my code is :

```
. : directory
./dir : directory
./dir/file : directory
```

And output of

```
echo `echo dir/file : ;if [ -f dir/file ]; then echo file; else echo directory;fi`
```

is

```
dir/file : file
```

I am working on `Ubuntu 14.10` and using `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2`

Comment: `find -exec bash -c 'echo -n "{} : ";if [ -f "{}" ]; then echo file; else echo directory;fi' \;`

Comment: Thanks @Costas but I know that using bash or sh I can achieve my initial goal, but now I want to understand why if behaves different with the exec parameter.

Comment: Put arguments into quotes `"{}"`. Why you use `echo` twice?

Comment: I already tried that and it gives the same output.
    find -exec echo `echo "{}" : ;if [ -f "{}" ]; then echo file; else echo directory;fi` \;

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, your snippet executes the command

```
echo {} : ;if [ -f {} ]; then echo file; else echo directory;fi
```

because it needs its output to evaluate the command substitution. Since there is no file named `{}`, this produces the output

```
{} :
directory
```

Then the `find` command is executed with the arguments `-exec`, `echo`, `{}`, `:`, `directory`, so for every file, it outputs the file name followed by a space and `: directory`.

What you actually want to do is to execute the shell snippet `echo {} :; …` on each file found by `find`. This snippet must be executed by a shell spawned by `find`, not by the shell that starts `find`, since it is receiving data from `find` on its command line. Therefore you need to instruct `find` to run a shell:

```
find -exec sh -c 'echo {} : ;if [ -f {} ]; then echo file; else echo directory;fi' \;
```

This is better, but still not right. It'll work with some (not all) `find` implementations if your file names don't contain any special characters, but since you are interpolating the file name in a shell script, you allow file names to execute arbitrary shell commands, e.g. if you have a file called `$(rm -rf /)` then the command `rm -rf /` will be executed. To pass file names to the script, pass them as separate arguments.

Also the first `echo` prints a newline after the colon. Use `echo -n` (if your shell supports it) or `printf` to avoid this.

```
find -exec sh -c 'printf "%s :" "$0"; if [ -f "$0" ]; then echo file; else echo directory; fi' {} \;
```

You can use `-exec … {} +` to group shell invocations, which is faster.

```
find -exec sh -c 'for x; do printf "%s :" "$x"; if [ -f "$x" ]; then echo file; else echo directory; fi; done' _ {} +
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way for executing `if; then; else; fi` together with `find` is:

```
find |
while IFS= read -r p; do if [ -f "$p" ]; then echo file; else echo directory; fi; done
```

Comment: Cool solution. It avoids complex quote patterns and subshell complications. You may have previously defined a shell function, and execute it on the files matching the "if" condition.

Comment: ... but see [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: In addition to the above comment, `whie read p` will trim filenames that contain leading and/or trailing whitespace, and it will also handle backslashes unpredictably.  `while IFS= read -r p` is more robust.