# Set sticky bit by default for new directories via ACL?

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

I want to set up a directory where all new files and directories have a certain access mask and also the directories have the sticky bit set (the `t` one, which restricts deletion of files inside those directories).

For the first part, my understanding is that I need to set the default ACL for the parent directory. However, new directories do not inherit the `t` bit from the parent. Hence, non-owners can delete files in the subdirectories. Can I fix that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a configuration that allows members of a group, *acltest*, to create
and modify group files while disallowing the deletion and renaming of files
except by their owner and "others," nothing. Using the username, *lev* and
assuming umask of 022:

```
groupadd acltest
usermod -a -G acltest lev
```

Log out of the root account and the *lev* account. Log in and become root or use *sudo*:

```
mkdir /tmp/acltest
chown root:acltest /tmp/acltest
chmod 0770 /tmp/acltest
chmod g+s /tmp/acltest
chmod +t /tmp/acltest

setfacl -d -m g:acltest:rwx /tmp/acltest
setfacl -m g:acltest:rwx /tmp/acltest
```

ACL cannot set the sticky bit, and the sticky bit is not copied to subdirectories. But, you might use *inotify* or similar software to detect changes in the file system, such as new directories, and then react accordingly.

For example, in Debian:

```
apt-get install inotify-tools
```

Then make a script for *inotify*, like `/usr/local/sbin/set_sticky.sh`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
inotifywait -m -r -e create /tmp/acltest |
while read path event file; do
    case "$event" in
        *ISDIR*)
            chmod +t $path$file
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Give it execute permission for *root*: `chmod 0700 /usr/local/sbin/set_sticky.sh`. Then run it at boot time from, say, `/etc/rc.local` or whichever RC file is appropriate:

```
/usr/local/sbin/set_sticky.sh &
```

Of course, in this example, `/tmp/acltest` should disappear on reboot. Otherwise, this should work like a charm.

Comment: This is what I have, but "disallowing the deletion and renaming of files except by their owner" is only in effect for files immediately under the parent directory, and not in new subdirectories, which I would like. Thank you anyway.

Comment: This is neat! Looks like in theory I don't even need ACLs in this case, because I can put all `chmod`s and `chown`s in the script, too. I'm using Arch Linux & `systemd`, so I'll try to write a service file that would start the script on boot. Also, some care must be taken about file names with spaces, but I see `inotifywait` has a `-c` option that is supposed to help with it.

Comment: You are right - ACLs don't seem to add any benefit. Thanks for the `-c` reference. Maybe quotes might help, too? `chmod +t "$path$file"`.

Comment: Yes, I ended up just adding quotes, the rest seems to work without `-c`.

Comment: unfortunately this will not scale for big directory trees. inotify is the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

## Setting the sticky bit recursively based on parent

Directories without the sticky bit can be found with below statement whereby the hyphen `-` in front of the value `1000` should be considered as [a prefix which will match this and higher permission values](http://www.tutonics.com/2012/12/find-files-based-on-their-permissions.html).

```
$ find . -type d \! -perm -1000
```

Hence, here is a way to set the sticky bit and `setgid` of those directories which parent directory has the sticky bit set.

That would call for a nested `find` statement, if it were not that [`find` statements cannot be nested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944626/2192488).

This is why rather a [pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/392720/39845) with a recursive conditional will be employed on the directories found without a sticky bit.
[The `-k` test](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) returns true if the sticky bit ---in this case, of the parent directory--- is set.

```
$ find . -type d \! -perm -1000 |while read d; do if [[ -k "$d/.." ]]; then chmod +t,g+s "$d"; fi; done
```

[Look here](http://hamwaves.com/find/en/index.html) for more `find` fun and [an explanation about `setgid`](http://hamwaves.com/find/en/index.html#prevent-others-from-deleting-files-inyourfolder).

Comment: Newly created subdirectories cannot inherit the sticky bit from their parent directory. Personally, I consider this a GNU/Linux deficiency.

Comment: Any UNIX-like w/o that deficiency? O_o

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function mkdir and append it to the end of your `vi ~/.bashrc` file as follows:

```
mkdir(){
    /bin/mkdir "$@"
    find . -type d \! -perm -1000 |while read d; do if [[ -k "$d/.." ]]; then chmod +t,g+s "$d"; fi; done
}
```

`-k` option checks if the sticky bit has been set, not GUID, that is set here too with `g+s`, check `man test` for these options

Also, you can do this:

```
unalias mkdir;
source ~/.bashrc
```

This should set the sticky bit for the new subdirectory, but only if the parent has the sticky bit set.

This method seemed to be working, but not sure for all users!