# Let a process read and write all files inside a certain directory, at any depth

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, acl, access-control

I have a directory, owned by me (e.g. `/sync`), and a process, run by me, which I want to have full read&write access to this directory (in my case the process is Resilio Sync, formerly known as BitTorrent Sync). All files in this directory are personal projects and documents. 99% of them are owned by me, but sometimes, for unavoidable reasons, some directories and files are created by root. How would I go about somehow letting the process alter, move and/or delete such directories and files?

I've tried a combination of sticky bits (setting `g+s` on `/sync`, so that all files inherit the group) and custom ACL rules (to try to have the sticky bits propagate to newly created directories automatically), but, as described in [this answer and its comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209029/21976), it can't be done without inotify (which I'd like to avoid for simplicity).

However, I was wondering, maybe there's some other way to go about this? Like giving one particular process more power in a certain directory and everything in it, ignoring all file permissions? And if that is possible, are there any security implications I would have to look out for?

Comment: `sudo chown -R youruser` before running the synch process.  Problem solved.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Resilio does the synchronization continuously, very much like Dropbox, just in a decentralized manner. It can decide to modify a root-owned file at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this goal requires sticky bits. Let's say the process is running as the user, `resilio`, and your user account is `olegs`. (I see that it is your account running the process; I add this for sake of demonstration.)

```
# Change all ownership to root:root
chown -R root:root /sync

# Make sure only root (and group members of root) can get a directory listing.
chmod 0750 /sync

# Now, let's augment standard permissions with ACLs.

# Set default masks for all new file system objects in /sync.
# (The root user already has permission.)
setfacl -d -m u:resilio:7 /sync
setfacl -d -m u:olegs:7 /sync

# Apply a mask to all existing files (and dirs) to give full control
# to the directory contents to olegs and resilio.

setfacl -m -R u:resilio:7 /sync
setfacl -m -R u:olegs:7 /sync
```

Now, these users have full control over the directory: `root`, `olegs`, and `resilio`. Otherwise, no other user can see the contents of the `/sync` directory. Although the masks specify `7` (read/write/execute), directories become rwx and files effectively become `6` (read/write).

Comment: Thanks, this works! At least it passes my elaborate test, comprised of `mkdir x`, `sudo touch x/y` and `rm x/y` :) I was doing it with groups, instead of users (`setfacl -m g:olegs:rwX /sync` & `setfacl -d -m g:olegs:rwX /sync`), with and without sticky bits. Not sure why it wasn't doing what I expected, but that's not important anymore.